# Cannot find the error with my 2D array java code

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, error-handling, syntax-error

Java says that there is an expected "]" error. I cannot find what is wrong with my code? The Song class is another class composition class and there is no problem with that. thanks in advance for help

```
public class Jukebox
{
    Song[][] songList;

    songList[0][0] = new Song("Jet Airliner", 5 );

    songList[0][1] = new Song( "Slide", 4 );

    songList[0][2] = new Song( "Tom Sawyer", 3 );
    songList[0][3] = new Song( "Purple Rain", 2 );
    songList[1][0] = new Song( "Sing a Song", 1 );
    songList[1][1] = new Song( "Baba O'Riley", 5 );
    songList[1][2] = new Song( "Jumper", 4 );
    songList[1][3] = new Song( "Car Wash", 3 );
    songList[2][0] = new Song( "Kung Fu Fighting", 2 );
    songList[2][1] = new Song( "Right as Rain", 4 );
    songList[2][2] = new Song( "Beat It", 5 );
    songList[2][3] = new Song( "Bust a Move", 4 );

    public  String toString()
    {
        String output = " ";
        for (int row = 0; row < songList.length; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < songList[row].length; col++)
            {
                output+=(songList[row][col]);
            }
            output += "\n";
        }
        return output;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**There are two problems**

1. songList needs to be initialized with a size of the array before you put in elements
2. songList[x][x]'s values should be set inside a constructor or method.

```
public class Jukebox {

    Song[][] songList = new Song[3][4];

    public Jukebox() {
        songList[0][0] = new Song("Jet Airliner", 5);
        songList[0][1] = new Song("Slide", 4);
        songList[0][2] = new Song("Tom Sawyer", 3);
        songList[0][3] = new Song("Purple Rain", 2);
        songList[1][0] = new Song("Sing a Song", 1);
        songList[1][1] = new Song("Baba O'Riley", 5);
        songList[1][2] = new Song("Jumper", 4);
        songList[1][3] = new Song("Car Wash", 3);
        songList[2][0] = new Song("Kung Fu Fighting", 2);
        songList[2][1] = new Song("Right as Rain", 4);
        songList[2][2] = new Song("Beat It", 5);
        songList[2][3] = new Song("Bust a Move", 4);
    }

    public String toString() {
        String output = " ";
        for (int row = 0; row < songList.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < songList[row].length; col++) {
                output += (songList[row][col]);
            }
            output += "\n";
        }
        return output;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Jukebox j = new Jukebox();
    }
}
```

**Song**

```
class Song {
    Song(String name, int i) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do all of the following in a method:

```
songList[0][0] = new Song("Jet Airliner", 5 );

songList[0][1] = new Song( "Slide", 4 );

songList[0][2] = new Song( "Tom Sawyer", 3 );
songList[0][3] = new Song( "Purple Rain", 2 );
songList[1][0] = new Song( "Sing a Song", 1 );
songList[1][1] = new Song( "Baba O'Riley", 5 );
songList[1][2] = new Song( "Jumper", 4 );
songList[1][3] = new Song( "Car Wash", 3 );
songList[2][0] = new Song( "Kung Fu Fighting", 2 );
songList[2][1] = new Song( "Right as Rain", 4 );
songList[2][2] = new Song( "Beat It", 5 );
songList[2][3] = new Song( "Bust a Move", 4 );
```

So you an create an `init()` method, or create a constructor if it suits your purpose.

```
public void init(){
    songList = new String[3][4];
    songList[0][0] = new Song("Jet Airliner", 5 );

    songList[0][1] = new Song( "Slide", 4 );

    songList[0][2] = new Song( "Tom Sawyer", 3 );
    songList[0][3] = new Song( "Purple Rain", 2 );
    songList[1][0] = new Song( "Sing a Song", 1 );
    songList[1][1] = new Song( "Baba O'Riley", 5 );
    songList[1][2] = new Song( "Jumper", 4 );
    songList[1][3] = new Song( "Car Wash", 3 );
    songList[2][0] = new Song( "Kung Fu Fighting", 2 );
    songList[2][1] = new Song( "Right as Rain", 4 );
    songList[2][2] = new Song( "Beat It", 5 );
    songList[2][3] = new Song( "Bust a Move", 4 );
}
```

Now before you call the `toString()` method of `JukeBox` you need to call the `init()` method.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
class Jukebox {

    private Song[][] songList;

    public Jukebox() {

        songList = new Song[3][4];

        songList[0][0] = new Song("Jet Airliner", 5);
        songList[0][1] = new Song("Slide", 4);
        songList[0][2] = new Song("Tom Sawyer", 3);
        songList[0][3] = new Song("Purple Rain", 2);

        songList[1][0] = new Song("Sing a Song", 1);
        songList[1][1] = new Song("Baba O'Riley", 5);
        songList[1][2] = new Song("Jumper", 4);
        songList[1][3] = new Song("Car Wash", 3);

        songList[2][0] = new Song("Kung Fu Fighting", 2);
        songList[2][1] = new Song("Right as Rain", 4);
        songList[2][2] = new Song("Beat It", 5);
        songList[2][3] = new Song("Bust a Move", 4);
    }


    public String toString() {
        String output = " ";
        for (int row = 0; row < songList.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < songList[row].length; col++) {
                output += (songList[row][col]);
            }
            output += "\n";
        }
        return output;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This program is syntactically wrong.
1. `Song[][] songList;` must be accompanied by a `new` operator.
2. At instance level, members can be initialized in one statement only. So below is wrong:

```
Song[][] songList;
songList[0][0] = new Song("Jet Airliner", 5 ); 
songList[0][1] = new Song( "Slide", 4 ); 
songList[0][2] = new Song( "Tom Sawyer", 3 ); 
songList[0][3] = new Song( "Purple Rain", 2 ); 
songList[1][0] = new Song( "Sing a Song", 1 ); 
songList[1][1] = new Song( "Baba O'Riley", 5 ); 
songList[1][2] = new Song( "Jumper", 4 ); 
songList[1][3] = new Song( "Car Wash", 3 ); 
songList[2][0] = new Song( "Kung Fu Fighting", 2 ); 
songList[2][1] = new Song( "Right as Rain", 4 ); 
songList[2][2] = new Song( "Beat It", 5 ); 
songList[2][3] = new Song( "Bust a Move", 4 );
```

Solutions:
1. Use `new` operator to instantiate the array.
`Song[][] songList = new Song[3][4];`

2. Either use initializer block or constructor to assign objects to array index.

   `class Jukebox
   {
     Song[][] songList = new Song[3][4];
     {
       //INIT Block for assignments
     }
   }`
3. Alternatively to #2, you can use array initializers.

   `Song[][] songList = new Song[][]{{}{}{}}`

Answer (score 0):

In Java, if you are going to assign a value to a class property, you should do it as soon as it is declared.

Instead of doing this:

```
Song[][] songList;

    songList[0][0] = new Song("Jet Airliner", 5 );

    songList[0][1] = new Song( "Slide", 4 );

    songList[0][2] = new Song( "Tom Sawyer", 3 );
    songList[0][3] = new Song( "Purple Rain", 2 );
    songList[1][0] = new Song( "Sing a Song", 1 );
    songList[1][1] = new Song( "Baba O'Riley", 5 );
    songList[1][2] = new Song( "Jumper", 4 );
    songList[1][3] = new Song( "Car Wash", 3 );
    songList[2][0] = new Song( "Kung Fu Fighting", 2 );
    songList[2][1] = new Song( "Right as Rain", 4 );
    songList[2][2] = new Song( "Beat It", 5 );
    songList[2][3] = new Song( "Bust a Move", 4 );
```

Try this one:

```
Song[][] songList = {
        {
            new Song("Jet Airliner", 5 ),
            new Song( "Slide", 4 ),
            new Song( "Tom Sawyer", 3 ),
            new Song( "Purple Rain", 2 )
        },
        {
            ...
        }

    };
```

Alternatively, you can do the assignment inside a constructor.

```
public Jukebox(){
songList = {
            {
                new Song("Jet Airliner", 5 ),
                new Song( "Slide", 4 ),
                new Song( "Tom Sawyer", 3 ),
                new Song( "Purple Rain", 2 )
            },
            {
                ...
            }

        };
}
```